# Stored procedure is not working and getting stopped

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I m running a piece of code for `scheduler` in my project. But it is not working as expected.

```
private void Initiate_User(string strEmpCard)
   {
       //conn.Open();
       ObjPriCmd = new SqlCommand("exec [sp_c_Initiate_Clearance] " + strEmpCard.ToString() + "", conn);
       ObjPriCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
```

The debugger stops and opens a form after my `ExecuteNonQuery()` line is debugged. I am not able to trace the error also. what is wrong here ??

**UPDATE**

My error query

```
insert into p_emp_clearance_hdr 
  (Emp_mkey,
  Emp_card_no, 
  RA_1,
  RA_2,
  Depatment, 
  Sub_Department, 
  Date_of_Joining, 
  Resignation_date, 
  Last_Working_Days, 
  UserId) 
select 
  em.mkey,
  em.emp_card_no,
  em.Reporting_To,
  em.Reporting_To2,
  em.Department_mkey,
  em.SubDept_mkey,
  convert(varchar(10), em.resig_date, 103) resig_date, 
  convert( varchar(10), em.Dt_Of_Join, 103) Dt_Of_Join, 
  convert(varchar(10), em.Dt_of_leave, 103) Dt_of_leave,
  um.mkey 
from emp_mst em join user_mst um 
on em.mkey = um.Employee_mkey
where em.mkey = @emp_mkey
```

Comment: If the code just stops running with no exception, try putting `ExecuteNonQuery()` in `try catch` block and set a breakpoint inside `catch` to see exception message.

Comment: @AlexJolig: let me check with that and let you know..!

Comment: @AlexJolig: I got error as `ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.`

Comment: 1) Naming user defined stored procedure with `sp_` is bad practice. 2) Possible SQL Injection, use parameter binding and avoid SQL string concatenation

Comment: Have you Defined conn before in class??

Comment: @lad2025: yes its a bad thing, but what's the issue here.

Comment: @yash: Yes, I have defined it as `SqlConnection conn;`

Comment: @coder: this Error comes when you have not initialized any connection before running Any Sql Command..

Comment: @yash: but I have alreday defined that, and i am getting my `string strEmpCard` value also

Comment: @coder: Better if you try it with using statement.....

Comment: @yash: can you tell how ???

Comment: you are putting string without quotes

Comment: @GeneR: so shd I use single quotes ?

Comment: yes, but better use an answer with parametrized query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you explained in comments, you are getting error:

> ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

It means you have not initialized the connection. You have just declared it:

```
SqlConnection conn;
```

You should do like:

```
conn = new SqlConnection(@"you connection string");
//then your code
ObjPriCmd = new SqlCommand("exec [sp_c_Initiate_Clearance] " + strEmpCard.ToString(), conn);
ObjPriCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**The best practice:**

You should use a `SqlCommand` property `CommandType` to define that you're calling a `StoredProcedure` when calling from `C#`. And define parameters using `SqlCommand .Parameters.Add` it handles the `SqlInjection` issues itself.

```
conn = new SqlConnection(@"you connection string");
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_c_Initiate_Clearance", conn)) 
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //                  parameter name  ,   parameter type              parameter value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameter name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strEmpCard.ToString();

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: but now I am getting error as `The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
The statement has been terminated.` I have posted the query which raised the error

Comment: What is the type of parameter you're passing? Is it `DateTime`?

Comment: The problem is with your date formats in table `emp_mst` in columns (`resig_date`, `Dt_Of_Join`, `Dt_of_leave`). Can you show a little data-set of this table?

Comment: May I ask what was the actual issue you encountered?

Comment: actually, while implementing that `SP` it was not triggering the error. It was just throwing window form

Answer (score 0):

You can Try it with USing Statement:-

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_c_Initiate_Clearance", conn)) {
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter Name", Type).Value = "Value of Parameter";
  conn.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: hi yash, now getting error as `The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
The statement has been terminated.` Posted the query in the question

Comment: Probl;em is in Your DateTime Parameter...Pass a DateTime into your Dates fields....